# Number of open connections and the meaning of sleeping status of a connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I ran this query in my database :

```
SELECT  
DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName,  
COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections, 
loginame as LoginName 
FROM 
    sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE  dbid > 0 
GROUP BY  dbid, loginame 

---------------------------------------------------
SELECT  COUNT(dbid) as TotalConnections 
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE  
dbid > 0 
---------------------------------------------------
exec sp_who2 'Active'
```

I want to know the total number of connections to my database. The sum of first query and amount of second query are equal but the third query returns a different number of rows.

I want to know what the third query returns? I see some of the status' in the result of the third query are `sleeping`. What does this mean? Is the connection idle, or it is ready in the pool? What does it mean if I have many `sleeping` connections in my result?

thanks

Comment: I don't think `sleeping` would be returned by the third query unless you ran it without specifying `'active'`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A status of `sleeping` means the session is connected but not actively running anything (e.g. the simplest definition, while perhaps not 100% accurate, is that there is nothing for that `session_id` in `sys.dm_exec_requests`).

`sp_who2 'active'` filters out any spid that has a status of `sleeping` or has a last command of `AWAITING COMMAND`, `LAZY WRITER` or `CHECKPOINT SLEEP`. No I did not memorize what `sp_who2` does; I simply looked at the source code:

```
EXEC master..sp_helptext sp_who2;
```

Note that `sp_who2` is undocumented and unsupported, and sysprocesses is deprecated and currently present only for backward compatibility reasons. You will be better served, I think, with a procedure like [Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com). Or at the very least knowing how to use the more modern DMVs like [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013(sql.100).aspx) and [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648(v=sql.100)).

**EDIT**

I should add the unfortunate disclaimer that the more modern DMVs still don't properly reveal the database(s) involved. But what does it really mean anyway? If you have a query like this:

```
USE database_A;
GO

SELECT [column] FROM database_B.dbo.[table] 
  UNION ALL
SELECT [column] FROM database_C.dbo.[table];
```

What database id do you expect will get reflected in `sys.sysprocesses.dbid` for that session while this query is running? I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to determine what actually happens. Long story short, that's not the view/column you want to rely on to know which databases are currently being "touched."

Comment: Does `sleeping` mean connection not closed after execute last command?

Comment: @Kerezo not necessarily; consider connection pooling, where connections are re-used even if the application explicitly closes the connection - this just returns the connection to the pool, but severing the connection to SQL Server and removing the row from `sys.dm_exec_sessions` would defeat the purpose of connection pooling.